# Loss value varying mid LSTM training

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, lstm

I'm currently working on a neural network project, and I need some help understanding the relationships between parameters and the values my neural network is outputing.

My goal is to train a LSTM neural network to detect stress in speech. I'm using a dataset divided into audios of neutral voices and audios of voices under stress. In order to classify which audios contain stress, I'm extracting relevant features from the voices each frame, and then feeding this information into the LSTM neural network.

Since I'm extracting features by frame, the extraction output from audio files with different lenghts also have different lenghts, proportionally to the audio duration. To normalize the neural networks inputs, I'm using a padding technique, which consists in adding zeroes to the end of each extracted features set to meet the biggest set size.

So, for example, if I have 3 audio files, each with these durations: 4, 5, 6 seconds, the extracted features set from the first two audios would be padded with zeroes to meet the third audio extracted set length.

A padded features set looks like this:

```
[
  [9.323346e+00, 9.222625e+00, 8.910659e+00],
  [8.751126e+00, 8.432300e+00, 8.046866e+00],
  ...
  [7.439109e+00, 7.380966e+00, 6.092496e+00],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0]
]
```

The whole dataset dimensions are as follows: (number of audio files) x (number of frames in biggest audio file) x (number of features)

I divided my dataset into a training set, a validation set and a test set. Currently, I have audio files from two public databases, one set with 576 audio files (288 non-stressed, 288 stressed) and other with 240 files (120 non-stressed, 120 stressed).

The following code shows my LSTM implementation using Keras:

```
N_HIDDEN_CELLS = 100
LEARNING_RATE = 0.00005
BATCH_SIZE = 32
EPOCHS_N = 30
ACTIVATION_FUNCTION = 'softmax'
LOSS_FUNCTION = 'binary_crossentropy'

def create_model(input_shape)
    model = keras.Sequential()

    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(N_HIDDEN_CELLS, input_shape=input_shape, return_sequences=True))

    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(N_HIDDEN_CELLS, return_sequences=True))

    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(N_HIDDEN_CELLS, return_sequences=True))

    model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.3))

    model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(2, activation=ACTIVATION_FUNCTION))

    return model

def prepare_datasets(data, labels, test_size, validation_size):
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, labels, test_size=test_size)
    X_train, X_validation, y_train, y_validation = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=validation_size)

    return X_train, X_validation, X_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test

X_train, X_validation, X_test, y_train, y_validation, y_test = prepare_datasets(data, labels, 0.25, 0.2)

input_shape = (X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])

model = create_model(input_shape)

optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=LOSS_FUNCTION, metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_validation, y_validation), batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS_N)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=2)
```

After various tests and executions, I'm not so confident about my network performance. At first, the validation loss values were all over the place, varying a lot and not converging at all. With some adjustments to parameters, I ended up with the values in the code above. Still, I'm not that confident, mainly because the validation loss starts to vary after epoch 15 (more or less). In the first epochs, both training and validation losses fall accordingly to expectations, but after some epochs, the training loss keeps falling and the validation loss starts to vary and rise.

Below are two executions of the same network (with the same parameters as the code provided) and same dataset (the one with 576 audio files):

```
Epoch 1/30
11/11 [==============================] - 5s 194ms/step - loss: 0.8493 - accuracy: 0.4934 - val_loss: 0.8436 - val_accuracy: 0.4943
Epoch 2/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 123ms/step - loss: 0.8398 - accuracy: 0.5271 - val_loss: 0.8364 - val_accuracy: 0.4943
Epoch 3/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 124ms/step - loss: 0.8291 - accuracy: 0.6015 - val_loss: 0.8277 - val_accuracy: 0.4828
Epoch 4/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 128ms/step - loss: 0.8187 - accuracy: 0.6022 - val_loss: 0.8159 - val_accuracy: 0.5402
Epoch 5/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 124ms/step - loss: 0.8017 - accuracy: 0.6691 - val_loss: 0.8002 - val_accuracy: 0.5862
Epoch 6/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 123ms/step - loss: 0.7754 - accuracy: 0.7081 - val_loss: 0.7750 - val_accuracy: 0.6322
Epoch 7/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 124ms/step - loss: 0.7455 - accuracy: 0.7168 - val_loss: 0.7391 - val_accuracy: 0.6092
Epoch 8/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 130ms/step - loss: 0.7017 - accuracy: 0.7287 - val_loss: 0.6896 - val_accuracy: 0.6437
Epoch 9/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 125ms/step - loss: 0.6519 - accuracy: 0.7210 - val_loss: 0.6311 - val_accuracy: 0.6897
Epoch 10/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 129ms/step - loss: 0.5613 - accuracy: 0.7817 - val_loss: 0.5935 - val_accuracy: 0.7356
Epoch 11/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 123ms/step - loss: 0.5050 - accuracy: 0.7789 - val_loss: 0.5645 - val_accuracy: 0.7471
Epoch 12/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 123ms/step - loss: 0.4612 - accuracy: 0.8098 - val_loss: 0.5127 - val_accuracy: 0.7356
Epoch 13/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 127ms/step - loss: 0.4117 - accuracy: 0.8301 - val_loss: 0.4848 - val_accuracy: 0.7931
Epoch 14/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 128ms/step - loss: 0.3857 - accuracy: 0.8479 - val_loss: 0.4609 - val_accuracy: 0.7816
Epoch 15/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 122ms/step - loss: 0.3392 - accuracy: 0.8724 - val_loss: 0.4467 - val_accuracy: 0.8276
Epoch 16/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 118ms/step - loss: 0.3140 - accuracy: 0.8901 - val_loss: 0.4462 - val_accuracy: 0.8161
Epoch 17/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 125ms/step - loss: 0.2775 - accuracy: 0.9092 - val_loss: 0.4619 - val_accuracy: 0.8046
Epoch 18/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 128ms/step - loss: 0.2963 - accuracy: 0.8873 - val_loss: 0.3995 - val_accuracy: 0.8621
Epoch 19/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 122ms/step - loss: 0.2663 - accuracy: 0.9141 - val_loss: 0.4364 - val_accuracy: 0.8276
Epoch 20/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 120ms/step - loss: 0.2415 - accuracy: 0.9368 - val_loss: 0.4758 - val_accuracy: 0.8276
Epoch 21/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 121ms/step - loss: 0.2209 - accuracy: 0.9297 - val_loss: 0.3855 - val_accuracy: 0.8276
Epoch 22/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 121ms/step - loss: 0.1605 - accuracy: 0.9676 - val_loss: 0.3658 - val_accuracy: 0.8621
Epoch 23/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 126ms/step - loss: 0.1618 - accuracy: 0.9641 - val_loss: 0.3638 - val_accuracy: 0.8506
Epoch 24/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 129ms/step - loss: 0.1309 - accuracy: 0.9728 - val_loss: 0.4450 - val_accuracy: 0.8276
Epoch 25/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 125ms/step - loss: 0.2014 - accuracy: 0.9394 - val_loss: 0.3439 - val_accuracy: 0.8621
Epoch 26/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 126ms/step - loss: 0.1342 - accuracy: 0.9554 - val_loss: 0.3356 - val_accuracy: 0.8851
Epoch 27/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 125ms/step - loss: 0.1555 - accuracy: 0.9618 - val_loss: 0.3486 - val_accuracy: 0.8736
Epoch 28/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 124ms/step - loss: 0.1346 - accuracy: 0.9659 - val_loss: 0.3208 - val_accuracy: 0.9080
Epoch 29/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 127ms/step - loss: 0.1193 - accuracy: 0.9697 - val_loss: 0.3706 - val_accuracy: 0.8851
Epoch 30/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 123ms/step - loss: 0.0836 - accuracy: 0.9777 - val_loss: 0.3623 - val_accuracy: 0.8621
5/5 - 0s - loss: 0.4383 - accuracy: 0.8472

Test accuracy: 0.8472222089767456

Test loss: 0.43826407194137573
```

[1st execution val_loss x train_loss graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJp6I.png)

```
Epoch 1/30
11/11 [==============================] - 5s 190ms/step - loss: 0.8297 - accuracy: 0.5306 - val_loss: 0.8508 - val_accuracy: 0.4138
Epoch 2/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 123ms/step - loss: 0.8138 - accuracy: 0.5460 - val_loss: 0.8355 - val_accuracy: 0.4713
Epoch 3/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 120ms/step - loss: 0.8082 - accuracy: 0.5384 - val_loss: 0.8145 - val_accuracy: 0.5402
Epoch 4/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 118ms/step - loss: 0.7997 - accuracy: 0.5799 - val_loss: 0.7911 - val_accuracy: 0.5517
Epoch 5/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 117ms/step - loss: 0.7752 - accuracy: 0.6585 - val_loss: 0.7654 - val_accuracy: 0.5862
Epoch 6/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 125ms/step - loss: 0.7527 - accuracy: 0.6609 - val_loss: 0.7289 - val_accuracy: 0.6437
Epoch 7/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 121ms/step - loss: 0.7129 - accuracy: 0.7432 - val_loss: 0.6790 - val_accuracy: 0.6782
Epoch 8/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 125ms/step - loss: 0.6570 - accuracy: 0.7707 - val_loss: 0.6107 - val_accuracy: 0.7356
Epoch 9/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 125ms/step - loss: 0.6112 - accuracy: 0.7513 - val_loss: 0.5529 - val_accuracy: 0.7586
Epoch 10/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 129ms/step - loss: 0.5339 - accuracy: 0.8026 - val_loss: 0.4895 - val_accuracy: 0.7816
Epoch 11/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 120ms/step - loss: 0.4720 - accuracy: 0.8189 - val_loss: 0.4579 - val_accuracy: 0.8046
Epoch 12/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 121ms/step - loss: 0.4332 - accuracy: 0.8527 - val_loss: 0.4169 - val_accuracy: 0.8046
Epoch 13/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 122ms/step - loss: 0.3976 - accuracy: 0.8568 - val_loss: 0.3850 - val_accuracy: 0.7931
Epoch 14/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 124ms/step - loss: 0.3489 - accuracy: 0.8726 - val_loss: 0.3753 - val_accuracy: 0.8046
Epoch 15/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 124ms/step - loss: 0.3088 - accuracy: 0.9020 - val_loss: 0.3562 - val_accuracy: 0.8161
Epoch 16/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 124ms/step - loss: 0.3489 - accuracy: 0.8745 - val_loss: 0.3501 - val_accuracy: 0.8391
Epoch 17/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 130ms/step - loss: 0.2725 - accuracy: 0.9240 - val_loss: 0.3436 - val_accuracy: 0.8506
Epoch 18/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 121ms/step - loss: 0.3494 - accuracy: 0.8764 - val_loss: 0.3516 - val_accuracy: 0.8506
Epoch 19/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 119ms/step - loss: 0.2553 - accuracy: 0.9243 - val_loss: 0.3413 - val_accuracy: 0.8391
Epoch 20/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 122ms/step - loss: 0.2723 - accuracy: 0.9092 - val_loss: 0.3258 - val_accuracy: 0.8621
Epoch 21/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 121ms/step - loss: 0.2600 - accuracy: 0.9306 - val_loss: 0.3257 - val_accuracy: 0.8506
Epoch 22/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 126ms/step - loss: 0.2406 - accuracy: 0.9411 - val_loss: 0.3203 - val_accuracy: 0.8966
Epoch 23/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 127ms/step - loss: 0.1892 - accuracy: 0.9577 - val_loss: 0.3191 - val_accuracy: 0.8851
Epoch 24/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 127ms/step - loss: 0.1869 - accuracy: 0.9594 - val_loss: 0.3246 - val_accuracy: 0.8621
Epoch 25/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 122ms/step - loss: 0.1898 - accuracy: 0.9487 - val_loss: 0.3217 - val_accuracy: 0.8851
Epoch 26/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 125ms/step - loss: 0.1731 - accuracy: 0.9523 - val_loss: 0.3280 - val_accuracy: 0.8506
Epoch 27/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 128ms/step - loss: 0.1445 - accuracy: 0.9687 - val_loss: 0.3213 - val_accuracy: 0.8851
Epoch 28/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 117ms/step - loss: 0.1441 - accuracy: 0.9718 - val_loss: 0.3212 - val_accuracy: 0.8621
Epoch 29/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 124ms/step - loss: 0.1250 - accuracy: 0.9762 - val_loss: 0.3232 - val_accuracy: 0.8851
Epoch 30/30
11/11 [==============================] - 1s 123ms/step - loss: 0.1460 - accuracy: 0.9687 - val_loss: 0.3218 - val_accuracy: 0.8736
5/5 - 0s - loss: 0.3297 - accuracy: 0.8889

Test accuracy: 0.8888888955116272

Test loss: 0.32971107959747314
```

[2nd execution val_loss x train_loss graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DtSn.png)

Some additional information:

- My labels are hot encoded.
- Frame step is 0.05s.
- Frame size is 0.125s.
- When running this configuration with the smaller dataset, I get a slightly different behaviour. The loss value falls more evenly, but kind of slowly. I tried increasing the epochs number, but after the 30th epoch the validation loss started to vary and rise as well.

My questions are:

- What could be causing this validation loss problem?
- What does it mean when a model has a high loss rate, but its accuracy remains ok?
- I read about binary cross entropy but I don't know if I understand what the loss value means in my tests, could someone help me understanding these values?
- Could this padding strategy be affecting the network performance?
- Is my input data and its dimensions coherent considering LSTM definitions?
- Could this be related to my dataset size?
- What would be an acceptable validation loss rate?

Answer (score 0):

Your validation loss being much higher than your training loss usually implies overfitting. Note that your `val_loss` isn't really *high*, it's just higher than the training loss. The validation accuracy isn't bad either, just much lower than on the training data which has effectively been memorized by your network.

Basically you need to reduce the strength of the model so it can generalize to the complexity of the problem at hand. Use more dropout and fewer parameters/layers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'll try adjustments you suggested.
About the loss, how can one tell if a loss value in "high"? I presume it depends on the loss function applied, but in my case, for example, what would be an unacceptable value?

Comment: Honestly it makes more sense to interpret the accuracy than the loss, though they tend to strongly correlate so that's why I said what I did. As for what accuracy is acceptable, depends on what you're doing. For example, running a convolutional network to classify MNIST digits (handwritten numbers) and getting only 80% accuracy would be a serious problem, since other people have achieved 99+%. But on a complex LSTM speech/emotion task, I think 80% accuracy is quite good.